# Webpack cannot resolve file imports not in current context directory

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6, import, require

I'm having a strange issue where, in my .js files, I cannot use an `import` or `require` statement to get a file that's outside of the current context directory.

Here is a screenshot of what my project directory looks like -

[Project directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eX0nL.jpg)

I have a simple file `templates.js` where I have a statement `require('./templates/test.hbs)`, used to get a Handlebars template that has been precompiled with the handlebars-loader plugin already set up through webpack. Upon running `webpack --mode development --watch --display-error-details`, here is the error I get, **basically saying that the path could not be resolved** (but looking at the outputted paths that tried to be resolved, it looks like the path to my .hbs file definitely exists):

[Console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQ3V6.jpg)

I've seen multiple variations of this problem around stack overflow but most seem to suggest either making a relative path that goes back to the root and then back to the desired folder (in my case, `../js/templates/test.hbs`, which I've tried, and does not work) or adding the `resolve` property to my webpack config file (which I've included below and also tried). Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my package.json (running Node v8.10.0 on Windows 10, npm v6.5.0)

```
{
  "main": "./dist/index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "develop": "webpack --mode development --watch --display-error-details",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.2.0",
    "auto-prefixer": "^0.4.2",
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "webpack": "^4.27.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "enhanced-resolve": "^4.1.0",
    "handlebars": "^4.0.12",
    "handlebars-loader": "^1.7.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2"
  }
}
```

Here is my webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/js/main.js',
    output: {
      filename: 'bundle.js',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.m?js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                    presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.hbs$/,
                loader: 'handlebars-loader',
            }
    ]},
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.hbs'],
        modules: ['src', 'src/js', 'src/js/templates', 'node_modules']
    },
    target: 'node'
  }
```